# Regarding relation between dimension of dual space of normed linear space X and dimension of X.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

I am solving assignments of a Institute of which I am not a student as our instructor never gives assignments.

Can somebody please help me with this problem . 
Question is -----> Prove that for every normed linear space X,
dimension of X' $\ge$  dimension of X. ( X' is dual space of X)

I am sorry but I am not able to think how to even start this problem. 
Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis of $X$, every vector $x\in X$ can be decomposed uniquely according to this basis
\begin{equation}
x = x^1 e_1 +\cdots+x^n e_n
\end{equation}
The map $f_i: x\mapsto x^i$ that maps every vector to its i-th coordinate on this basis is a linear functional on the space $X$, that is to say $f_i \in X'$.

**Hint:** Prove that $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are linearly independent in $X'$.

Comment: Then dimension would be proved equal how to prove it greater than or equal to  dimension of X.

Comment: I proved $ f_i $ to be Linearly independent but how to prove dimension  of X' could be  greater than dimension of X

Comment: @user686624 If there are $n$ independent elements in $X'$, it implies that the dimension of $X'$ is at least $n$. But $n$ is the dimension of $X$.